# Why my bootstrap textboxes have shrinked in width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

A day before shutting down my pc My `form-control` textboxes were perfect and normal as they were. Now today I open my project and in all forms where ever `form-control` textboxes are used they look like this now

[image]

I tried

```
.form-control
{
width: 20px
}
```

nothing happened

Comment: why `width` it's `height` problemo mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your main file or html page where you have given Bootstrap links and scripts and add these

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Check if these original script changes the view

Comment: Okay this seemed idiotic. Yess it worked. I guess my custom bootstrap is the issue

Answer (score 0):

May be your input type will be number so that's why the up and down arrow is displayed,  if your input type is number give it a type of text hope  this will solve your issue..

Comment: No! I have `type="text", type="email"` too they all shrinked bruh